# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I want to redirect all my `http` traffic to redirect to `https`. I am using `letsencrypt`. I read online that `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;` would redirect all the traffic to my website over to `https` but instead it results in `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Everything works fine without the above mention statement, but then I have to specifically specify `https` in the URL. Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.me/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.me/privkey.pem;

        root /home/website/mywebsite/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name mywebsite.me www.mywebsite.me;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change your config to below

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name mywebsite.me www.mywebsite.me;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.me/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.me/privkey.pem;

        root /home/website/mywebsite/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name mywebsite.me www.mywebsite.me;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Your current config redirects on both http and https to https. So it becomes a infinite loop because of the return statement. You want return statement only when connection is http. So you split it into two server blocks

Answer (score 93):

In my case it was Cloudflare. I had to change to Full SSL encryption

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Comment: You are a hero.

Comment: As soon as i read CloudFlare i was like "omg i forgot about that completely". Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Yes, I use Cloudflare but still, when you have multiple server blocks it won't force redr to HTTPS is still allows HTTP

Comment: Give this guy a medal, please! :D

Comment: Would anyone please explain why Cloudflare full SSL would do the job?

Comment: Dude! This should be an accepted answer!

Comment: Annoying that Cloudflare has either changed their default to be "Flexible" rather than "Full" or I misconfigured it on moving the domain across - either way this caught me out big style! Thanks!

Comment: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216475197-Cloudflare-with-SSL-overview

The link to do so.

Comment: Absolutely bloody brilliant, you saved me!

Comment: If I could kiss you I would. Thank you!!!

Comment: your answer just saved me from more than 2 hours of headache. thanks a lot bro

Comment: Took me all day, but some how managed to find this answer, which is a life saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

i had the same problem. i found lots of questions/answers and articles about it but nothing helped.
i then tried to access my site from a different browser and it worked just fine!
deleting the cache from my chrome browser solved it.

So - keep in mind when you try different solutions to also clear your cache

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ZyQux: Have domain on Cloudflare, which redirecting to another VPS provider, where Certbot. There was loop redirect. To fix it, I have had to switch off proxy (to "DNS only") in DNS management of domain:

[image]

Thus thanks to @OritK because after fixing it on Cloudflare even  incognito Chrome was showing error on my website. So yes, check it in FireFox