# Certbot Redirection of HTTP to HTTPS from Nginx is not working

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm setting ssl server on Nginx with proxy_pass to apache.

The code was recreated by certbot and is not working. I can't find out what's wrong.

I've also tried to replace $host by $server_name and other suggestions from forum with no success.

```
    server {
        server_name biofit.blog www.biofit.blog;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/gekko.winsum.ws/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gekko.winsum.ws/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
                proxy_pass http://biofit.blog:81;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
                proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
        }
    }

    server {
       if ($host = www.biofit.blog) {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
      if ($host = biofit.blog) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name biofit.blog www.biofit.blog;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

The expected output of ssl should  pass to apache running on port 81, but not:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: curl -I  http://biofit.blog
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 20:03:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://biofit.blog/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERR\_TOO\_MANY\_REDIRECTS with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413494/err-too-many-redirects-with-nginx)

Comment: It seems that the redirect is originating from PHP. You should check your application.

Answer (score 1):

it's not recommended to use if statement
try this:

```
    server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name biofit.blog www.biofit.blog;
        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```