# NGINX giving me `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in the browser, but no error is showing in the terminal

Tags: php, django, nginx, deployment

I have a set up a nginx on subdomain `backend.globeofarticles.com`, and the frontend is served on cloudfare on domain `www.globeofarticles.com` and `globeofarticles.com`, also my code for the backend is deployed on a vps, the frontend is deployed on cloudfare, the main problem is that nginx is giving me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on the browser, screenshot:
[image]

here is some code that might help tracking the problem:

on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file :

````
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;
        
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/x$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        # # EDIT HERE include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
``` indentation might not be at its best here

on ` /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ArticleWebsite` file:



```nginx


server_tokens               off;
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/ArticleWebsite.access.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/ArticleWebsite.error.log;

# This configuration will be changed to redirect to HTTPS later
server {
  server_name               backend.globeofarticles.com;
  listen                    443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.globeofarticles.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.globeofarticles.com/privkey.pem;
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  }
}
````

when I try `sudo nginx -T` i get no error as it seem, however i get some code there (similar to these i posted above), also `sudo systemctl status nginx` is giving me `running` in green color, so everything seems fine, if anything else need to be provided please tell

Comment: Did you see this question here? It mentions Cloudflare and having to enable full SSL on there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413494/err-too-many-redirects-with-nginx

Comment: @cantsay, when i switch to full SSL, i get bad gateway error (status code 502) on the browser.

Comment: What happens if you disable Cloudflare by setting it to DNS only (so traffic isn't proxied via it's servers)?

Comment: @cantsay i get `bad gateway 502` with a horizontal line, and under that line i get `nginx`, so it seem like nginx generated the error?